# Libgdx Robovm : java.io.IOException: File is not an archive file

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, libgdx, robovm

I have successfully built my apt for android with Android Studio and the framework libgdx.
I am now trying to do the same for the iOS version.

However when trying to compile the iOS version with robovm, I have the following error:

```
[INFO] 13:03:17.478 classpath entry: /Users/<username>/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.android.gms/play-services-tasks/17.0.0/18299a334d48bc5abfe3c9446c2a9e1a3b3f38e1/play-services-tasks-17.0.0.aar
[INFO] 13:03:17.478 Using SDK boot classpath
[ERROR] Couldn't compile app
java.io.IOException: File is not an archive file: /Users/<username>/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.legacy/legacy-support-core-ui/1.0.0/61a264f996046e059f889914050fae1e75d3b702/legacy-support-core-ui-1.0.0.aar
    at org.robovm.compiler.clazz.Clazzes.addPaths(Clazzes.java:85)
    at org.robovm.compiler.clazz.Clazzes.<init>(Clazzes.java:55)
    at org.robovm.compiler.config.Config.build(Config.java:997)
    at org.robovm.compiler.config.Config.access$5400(Config.java:110)
    at org.robovm.compiler.config.Config$Builder.build(Config.java:1632)
    at org.robovm.idea.compilation.RoboVmCompileTask.compileForRunConfiguration(RoboVmCompileTask.java:290)
    at org.robovm.idea.running.RoboVmBeforeRunTaskProvider$1.run(RoboVmBeforeRunTaskProvider.java:97)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:888)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:585)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:531)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:150)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.lambda$run$0(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:221)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:238)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here is my build.gradle for my project:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        //https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/libgdx-site/service/getVersions?release=false
        gdxVersion = '1.9.10'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.10-SNAPSHOT'
        roboVMGradleVersion = '2.3.10-SNAPSHOT'
        androidToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
        androidSDKVersion = '28'
        androidGradleToolsVersion = '3.4.2'
        gwtVersion = '2.8.2'
        gwtGradleVersion = '1.0.9'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
        gdxPayVersion = '0.11.4'
        googleSrvVersion = '3.2.0'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.wisepersist:gwt-gradle-plugin:$gwtGradleVersion"
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$androidGradleToolsVersion"
        classpath "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:$roboVMGradleVersion"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:$googleSrvVersion"
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "MonBots RPG"
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" } //add this line
        maven { url  "https://adcolony.bintray.com/AdColony"}
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"

        implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:18.0.0"
        implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-android-googlebilling:$gdxPayVersion"

        // For @Nullable/@NonNull
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'

        implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:4.1.4.1'
        implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:unity:3.4.2.3'
        implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:tapjoy:12.4.2.0'
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        implementation "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        implementation "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"

        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-iosrobovm-apple:$gdxPayVersion"

        implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:4.1.4.1'
        implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:unity:3.4.2.3'
        implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:tapjoy:12.4.2.0'
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"

        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.esotericsoftware.spine:spine-libgdx:3.7.0.1"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-client:$gdxPayVersion"
        implementation 'com.esotericsoftware:kryonet:2.22.0-RC1'
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Here is the build.gradle of the iOS module

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

ext {
    mainClassName = "com.monbots.IOSLauncher"
}

launchIPhoneSimulator.dependsOn build
launchIPadSimulator.dependsOn build
launchIOSDevice.dependsOn build
createIPA.dependsOn build


eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-ios"
    natures 'org.robovm.eclipse.RoboVMNature'
}
```

I have tried to find a similar issue on google without any luck.
Do you have any idea how to resolve this ?

Thank you in advance,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found it, I have put the wrong implementation in the iOS piece for my ads:

```
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:4.1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:unity:3.4.2.3'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:tapjoy:12.4.2.0'
```

I have to use robopods for this.